# Docker Commit takes a lot of time

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am pursuing the following course :
https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud730/lessons/6452084188/concepts/65798813760923
I have setup docker and installed TenorFlow
I have created a container and downloaded notMnist images
when i commit this, docker is taking a lot of time and not commiting
Please resolve
Edit : Please note it is running from hours.

Comment: Your question has been downvoted for a couple of reasons. It's unspecific, you haven't told us symptoms or things you've tried, and you're not actually asking a specific question, you're asking us to solve it. In this case, you got lucky because your question is common enough that someone recognized the behavior despite that. In the future, you should probably try to take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Better questions will get better answers.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the linked question and [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/), the commit on a running container pauses the running application. This takes time.

> By default, the container being committed and its processes will be
>   paused while the image is committed. This reduces the likelihood of
>   encountering data corruption during the process of creating the
>   commit. If this behavior is undesired, set the --pause option to
>   false.

Comment: What are the risks if i use --pause option ?

Comment: Your application corrupts the commit.

Comment: What if i manually download dataset and copy it to an image using cp command and then commit ?